# How can I get the SQL query object or parse tree in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to analyze the queries run against a MySQL database, in order to see which tables, columns etc are being accessed. Potentially I might do query rewriting too.

Does MySQL provide a callback/hook where it can give me the query information as a parsed object, instead of the raw string that gets logged to the files.

I read about the [Audit Plugin API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/writing-audit-plugins.html) but it too passes the query as a string and not in a structured format.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple SQL parser suffice?  It won't validate against your database schema (then again, perhaps there are some that will), but does that matter?

Comment: The queries are run via a program, and I'm trying to analyze the run-time behaviour of the program based on the queries. I suppose you mean parse the MySQL query log? Yes, I could do that. But since MySQL parses the query anyway, I was wondering if it can give me the parsed representation itself.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I've been studying the problem also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Does MySQL provide a callback/hook where it can give me the query information as a parsed object, instead of the raw string that gets logged to the files.
```

No, there is no such interface.

There is no abstract syntax tree either, the parser produces structures that are very coupled with the server runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is an AQT: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=4533 .
But it only converts the MySQL query to a tree, and doesn't take your database in to consideration